# Expected value of Squared Error

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, machine-learning, regression

In the book [Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/%7Egareth/ISL/), chapter 2, there is a section about prediction using regression. That is, given input $\mathrm X$ and a known quantitative response $\mathrm Y$, we have the relation

$$
\mathrm Y = f(\mathrm X) + \epsilon
$$

where $\epsilon$ is random error term. We can then learn a function $\hat f$ that can predict $\mathrm{\hat Y}$ as
$$
\hat Y = \hat f(X)
$$

In this case, the expected value of squared error described in the book is:
$$
E(Y - \hat Y)^2 = E[f(X) + \epsilon - \hat f(X)]^2
$$
$$
= [f(X) - \hat f(X)]^2 + Var(\epsilon)
$$

I am unable to work out exactly how this derivation works using the basic rules about random variables that I know. How does the expected value ($E$) on the right hand side disappear?

Comment: I don't see how the expected value could possibly disappear like that. I don't have this book, so I can't look, but I wonder if it might be a typo. Assuming it *is* a typo, it looks like the rest of the last expression can be obtained by assuming that $E[f(X) - \hat{f}(X)] = 0$ and that $\epsilon$ and $f(X) - \hat{f}(X)$ are uncorrelated.

Comment: It could be a typo. Although it is not listed in the errata section for the book.

Comment: Well, it doesn't make sense as written. I maintain it's a typo. You could always email the author(s)...

Comment: Please, take a look at [this post](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/27830/2444).